# Pandas Dataframe Merging Issue

Tags: python, pandas

I need to merge the following 2 dataframes:

```
df1:
     A    B    C    D    F
0    1    a   zz   10   11
1    1    a   zz   15   11
2    2    b   yy   20   12
3    3    c   xx   30   13
4    4    d   ww   40   14
5    5    e   vv   50   15
6    6    f   uu   60   16
7    7    g  NaN   70   17
8    8    h   ss   80   18
9    9  NaN   rr   90   19
10  13    m   nn  130  113
11  15    o   ll  150  115

df2:
    A    B    C    D     G
0   1  NaN   zz   15   100
1   6    f   uu   60   600
2   7    g   tt   70   700
3  10    j   qq  100  1000
4  12    l  NaN  120  1200
5  14    n  NaN  140  1400
```

The merged dataframe should be:

```
     A    B    C    D     F     G
0    1    a   zz   10    11  None
1    1    a   zz   15    11   100
2    2    b   yy   20    12  None
3    3    c   xx   30    13  None
4    4    d   ww   40    14  None
5    5    e   vv   50    15  None
6    6    f   uu   60    16   600
7    7    g   tt   70    17   700
8    8    h   ss   80    18  None
9    9  NaN   rr   90    19  None
10  13    m   nn  130   113  None
11  15    o   ll  150   115  None
12  10    j   qq  100  None  1000
13  12    l  NaN  120  None  1200
14  14    n  NaN  140  None  1400
```

Following is the code to generate df1 and df2:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 13, 15],
                    'B': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', np.NAN, 'm', 'o'],
                    'C': ['zz', 'zz', 'yy', 'xx', 'ww', 'vv', 'uu', np.NAN, 'ss', 'rr', 'nn', 'll'],
                    'D': [10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 130, 150],
                    'F': [11, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 113, 115]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 6, 7, 10, 12, 14],
                    'B': [np.NAN, 'f', 'g', 'j', 'l', 'n'],
                    'C': ['zz', 'uu', 'tt', 'qq', np.NAN, np.NAN],
                    'D': [15, 60, 70, 100, 120, 140],
                    'G': [100, 600, 700, 1000, 1200, 1400]})
```

I tried the following methods:

```py
md1 = df1.merge(df2, how='outer')
md2 = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on=['A', 'D'])
md3 = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', left_on=['A', 'D'], right_on=['A', 'D'])
md4 = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', left_on=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], right_on=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

Following are the results of md1 and md4 (same result):

```py
print(md1.to_string())
     A    B    C    D      F       G
0    1    a   zz   10   11.0     NaN
1    1    a   zz   15   11.0     NaN
2    2    b   yy   20   12.0     NaN
3    3    c   xx   30   13.0     NaN
4    4    d   ww   40   14.0     NaN
5    5    e   vv   50   15.0     NaN
6    6    f   uu   60   16.0   600.0
7    7    g  NaN   70   17.0     NaN
8    8    h   ss   80   18.0     NaN
9    9  NaN   rr   90   19.0     NaN
10  13    m   nn  130  113.0     NaN
11  15    o   ll  150  115.0     NaN
12   1  NaN   zz   15    NaN   100.0
13   7    g   tt   70    NaN   700.0
14  10    j   qq  100    NaN  1000.0
15  12    l  NaN  120    NaN  1200.0
16  14    n  NaN  140    NaN  1400.0
```

Following are the results of md2 and md3 (same result):

```py
print(md2.to_string())
     A  B_x  C_x    D      F  B_y  C_y       G
0    1    a   zz   10   11.0  NaN  NaN     NaN
1    1    a   zz   15   11.0  NaN   zz   100.0
2    2    b   yy   20   12.0  NaN  NaN     NaN
3    3    c   xx   30   13.0  NaN  NaN     NaN
4    4    d   ww   40   14.0  NaN  NaN     NaN
5    5    e   vv   50   15.0  NaN  NaN     NaN
6    6    f   uu   60   16.0    f   uu   600.0
7    7    g  NaN   70   17.0    g   tt   700.0
8    8    h   ss   80   18.0  NaN  NaN     NaN
9    9  NaN   rr   90   19.0  NaN  NaN     NaN
10  13    m   nn  130  113.0  NaN  NaN     NaN
11  15    o   ll  150  115.0  NaN  NaN     NaN
12  10  NaN  NaN  100    NaN    j   qq  1000.0
13  12  NaN  NaN  120    NaN    l  NaN  1200.0
14  14  NaN  NaN  140    NaN    n  NaN  1400.0
```

But none of the above results is what I need from the merge operation!

So, I wrote a function to get what I want:

```py
def merge_df(d1, d2, on_columns):
    d1_row_count = d1.shape[0]
    d2_row_count = d2.shape[0]
    d1_columns = list(d1.columns)
    d2_columns = list(d2.columns)
    extra_columns_in_d1 = []
    extra_columns_in_d2 = []
    common_columns = []
    for c in d1_columns:
        if c not in d2_columns:
            extra_columns_in_d1.append(c)
        else:
            common_columns.append(c)
    for c in d2_columns:
        if c not in d1_columns:
            extra_columns_in_d2.append(c)
    print(common_columns)
    # start with the merged dataframe equal to d1
    md = d1.copy(deep=True)
    # Append the extra columns to md (with None values in the newly appended columns)
    for c in extra_columns_in_d2:
        md[c] = [None] * d1_row_count
    d1_new_row_number = d1_row_count
    # iterate thru each row in d2
    for i in range(d2_row_count):
        # create the match query string
        d1_match_condition = ''
        for p, c in enumerate(on_columns):
            d1_match_condition += c + ' == ' + str(d2.loc[i, c])
            if p < (len(on_columns) - 1):
                d1_match_condition += ' and '
        match_in_d1 = d1.query(d1_match_condition)
        # if match is not found, then append the row
        if match_in_d1.shape[0] == 0:
            # build a list representing the row to append
            row_list = []
            for c in common_columns:
                row_list.append(d2.loc[i, c])
            for c in extra_columns_in_d1:
                row_list.append(None)
            for c in extra_columns_in_d2:
                row_list.append(d2.loc[i, c])
            md.loc[d1_new_row_number] = row_list
            d1_new_row_number += 1
        # if match is found, then modify the found row
        else:
            match_in_d1_index = list(match_in_d1.index)[0]
            for c in common_columns:
                if (md.loc[match_in_d1_index, c]) is None or (md.loc[match_in_d1_index, c]) is np.NAN:
                    md.loc[match_in_d1_index, c] = d2.loc[i, c]
            for c in extra_columns_in_d2:
                md.loc[match_in_d1_index, c] = d2.loc[i, c]
    return md
```

When I use this function, I get the desired merged dataframe:

```py
md5 = merge_df(df1, df2, ['A', 'D'])
```

Am I missing something basic with the inbuilt dataframe merge method to get the desired result?

Comment: Can you explain in words, what is your merging logic?

Comment: Why the downvote to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could merge first then use `.assing` and `.combine_first`. The resulting columns of the merge need to put to toghether correctly by taking the value of the right `df` and update its value with the left `df` it has an entry at this specific point. This is what `.combine_first` does.

```
m = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['A','D'], how='outer')
m.assign(B=m['B_x'].combine_first(m['B_y']), C=m['C_x'].combine_first(m['C_y']))\
    .drop(['B_x','C_x','B_y','C_y'], 1)[['A','B','C','D','F','G']]
```

result

```
    A   B   C   D   F       G
0   1   a   zz  10  11.0    NaN
1   1   a   zz  15  11.0    100.0
2   2   b   yy  20  12.0    NaN
3   3   c   xx  30  13.0    NaN
4   4   d   ww  40  14.0    NaN
5   5   e   vv  50  15.0    NaN
6   6   f   uu  60  16.0    600.0
7   7   g   tt  70  17.0    700.0
8   8   h   ss  80  18.0    NaN
9   9   NaN rr  90  19.0    NaN
10  13  m   nn  130 113.0   NaN
11  15  o   ll  150 115.0   NaN
12  10  j   qq  100 NaN     1000.0
13  12  l   NaN 120 NaN     1200.0
14  14  n   NaN 140 NaN     1400.0
```

Comment: Do i need to install something or do something to make this work? Because, PyCharm says 'this statement seems to have no effect' (for the m.assign line), and the result I get is different (the _x and _y colums still exist)...

Comment: well if you want to use the result just do `m_new = m.assing(...)` so that you save the result of the `assign` operation. If you do so, PyCharm realizes that this statement does actually have an effect and you will see that the `_x` cols are dropped

Comment: most of the pandas operations do not work inplace so you need to assign the result after performing transformations

Comment: Although this is an elegant solution, it leaves me wondering: isn't MERGE supposed to do what we have achieved with merge+assign+combine_first+drop...

Comment: Nope because first of all you need to have an outer join, since you want the results from both dfs even if the have no corresponding key in the other df. Then we have to use a  `coalesce `-like operation to get the df in the desired form because after the merge we have some duplicated column.

Answer (score 1):

You have the format wrong on merge operation. Try the following code

```
result = df1.merge(df2,on=['A','D'], how='outer')
```

try this

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2,on=['A','D'],how='outer')
df1['C'] = df1[['C_x','C_y']].apply(lambda x: x['C_y'] if x['C_x'] is np.nan else x['C_x'],axis=1)
df1['B'] = df1[['B_x','B_y']].apply(lambda x: x['B_y'] if x['B_x'] is np.nan else x['B_x'],axis=1)
df1 = df1.drop(labels=['B_x','B_y','C_x','C_y'],axis=1)
```

Comment: This results in columns getting duplicated with a '_x' and '_y' as in md2 and md3 results that i have shared, plus the last 3 rows from df2 are lost!

Comment: Can you post code to form your dataframe or a csv file to read from

Comment: I have added a very simple approach. I hope that works for you. I tried checking a few rows and they match

Comment: The last 3 rows from df2 are now showing NaN values in the merged dataframe for columns B,C and F :(

Comment: It was nice talking to you. Let me know, if you need anything else